# I can't figure out how to filter or query in Google Sheets without returning a bunch of blank strings appended to actual data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm at my wit's end on trying to figure out why filtering/querying in Google Sheets is so broken. I have a sheet with some data about practice exams I'm taking and I'm attempting to pull some data from that sheet to another sheet for calculating statistics. I've made a [shareable document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nTFP2SdoXrPbStSk83Ye7T-IM0edNe9id9Z9Gm6i23g/edit?usp=sharing) with the pertinent stuff so you can see what I mean.

My raw data is in the `TestScores` sheet and I made a `TESTSTATS` sheet to test different methods of pulling data from `TestScores`. In my example, I'm only trying to pull unique dates from range `TestScores!B2:B` and I've added a few different methods to do so in `TESTSTATS` (removed the equal sign from each one so each can be tested on its own by putting in the equal sign).

The methods I've tried:

1. `=UNIQUE(TestScores!B2:B)`
2. `=UNIQUE(FILTER(TestScores!B2:B, TestScores!B2:B<>""))`
3. `=UNIQUE(FILTER(TestScores!B2:B, TestScores!B2:B<>0))`
4. `=UNIQUE(FILTER(TestScores!B2:B, NOT(ISBLANK(TestScores!B2:B))))`
5. `=UNIQUE(QUERY(TestScores!B2:B, "select B"))`
6. `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(UNIQUE(QUERY(TestScores!B2:B, "select B")), ROWS(UNIQUE(TestScores!B2:B))+1,5)`

You'll see that each one, when activated by adding the `=` in front of the formula returns the proper data, but also appends 500 empty rows which look empty, but are in fact blank strings `("")`. This makes it difficult to work with because there are a lot of calculations in my sheet that depend on one another. I also do not want to specify an explicit end to my ranges and would prefer to keep them open ended (`B2:B` instead of `B2:B17`) so everything updates automatically as new records are added.

What am I doing wrong? Why are the returned data appended with a bunch of empty cells, and why 500 specifically (seems arbitrary considering my source data is 29 or 30 rows depending on whether or not you include headers)?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with only two rows in `TESTSTATS` more rows have to be added for somewhere to place the output. It seems Google choose to do so 500 rows at a time (from the last required cell). "Why?" would have to be a matter for Google.

If you know 14 rows are required for the output and increase the size of `TESTSTATS` to 16 no more rows will be added. Since you want room for expansion you can't extend to 16 and avoid further issues but you could allow some room, say to 30 rows, and delete the few extra, or, if 30 becomes insufficient (when sheet shoots up to say 540 rows) delete the rows not required but set the sheet size to say 60 rows - and so on.

Comment: Hmm, that's very limiting for keeping things tidy/error-free. My example sheet is simplistic, but the sheet I'm working on has a lot of cross-referencing and it's a hassle ensuring this propagation of rows doesn't break things (array formulas and scripts). There's also no documentation on Google's side on how it determines the number of empty rows to add. In this case, it seems to be 500, but I have other sheets where it adds more or less. I imagine it has something to do with the formula being used, but I have no way of knowing what the criteria are. Thank you for the explanation though!